# JDBC connection error while using mondrian

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2012, pentaho, mondrian

After installing and configuring `Pentaho Mondrian` the below exception is thrown (complete stack trace):

```
mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Internal error:    Connect string '@mondrian.webapp.connectString@=; Catalog='null'' must contain either 'Jdbc' or 'DataSource'     
    at mondrian.resource.MondrianResource$_Def0.ex(MondrianResource.java:813)
    at mondrian.olap.Util.newInternal(Util.java:1485)   
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.createDataSource(RolapConnection.java:423)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.<init>(RolapConnection.java:149)
    at mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.<init>(RolapConnection.java:92)   
    at mondrian.olap.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:110)    
    at mondrian.olap.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:74)     
    at mondrian.olap.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:55)     
    at mondrian.web.servlet.MdxQueryServlet.processRequest(MdxQueryServlet.java:90)
    at mondrian.web.servlet.MdxQueryServlet.doGet(MdxQueryServlet.java:241)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)     
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:843)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:679)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have done the configuration in mondrian.properties, `datasources.xml` and `web.xml`
my `jdbc` string looks like this:

```
mondrian.test.connectString=Provider=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=foodmart;Catalog=/WEB-INF/queries/FoodMart.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
```

Comment: Can you put the whole `connectionString` in single quotes like this:`mondrian.test.connectString='Provider=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;
databaseName=foodmart;
Catalog=/WEB-INF/queries/FoodMart.xml;
JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;'`

Comment: @gotqn i tried with single quotes as you told; but same exception is printed.

Comment: Then try using this format in the both XML files: `<init-param>
<param-name>connectString</param-name>
<param-value>Provider=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://‌​localhost:1433; databaseName=foodmart; Catalog=/WEB-INF/queries/FoodMart.xml; JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;<param-value>
</init-param>`

Comment: @gotqn It is the same exception again !